# display values returned by json

Tags: ajax, json

I have simple question to display data on html page. Following code displays array of json data on screen. but, I want to display it by each element such as "url", "img_url" and so on.
could you please let me know who to do it ?

ajax code

```
var dataString =  'url=' + pathname + '&img_name=' + img_name + "&tag=" + tag;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "image_finder.php",
       data: dataString,
       dataType: 'json',
       complete: function (xhr, status) {
        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
            //handleError();

            alert("error");

        } else {
            var data = xhr.responseText;



            $('#tt').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                                $('#message').html(data);



        }
    }
    });
```

json return

```
{"cid":"14","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/","img_url":"http:\/\/static.naver.net\/www\/up\/2013\/0305\/mat_173330634c.jpg","img_name":"mat_173317134c.jpg","html":"<div id=\"hotspot-19\" class=\"hs-wrap hs-loading\">\r\n<img src=\"http:\/\/static.naver.net\/www\/up\/2013\/0305\/mat_173330634c.jpg\">\r\n<div class=\"hs-spot-object\" data-type=\"spot\" data-x=\"95\" data-y=\"64\" data-width=\"30\" data-height=\"30\" data-popup-position=\"left\" data-visible=\"visible\" data-tooltip-width=\"200\" data-tooltip-auto-width=\"true\">\r\nasdf\r\n<\/div>\r\n<div class=\"hs-spot-object\" data-type=\"spot\" data-x=\"168\" data-y=\"53\" data-width=\"30\" data-height=\"30\" data-popup-position=\"left\" data-visible=\"visible\" data-tooltip-width=\"200\" data-tooltip-auto-width=\"true\">\r\nrere\r\n<\/div>\r\n<\/div>\r\n","jscript":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "image_finder.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        for(var item in data){
            console.info(item);//print key
            console.info(data[item]);//print value
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: $.each( data, function(key,value) {
     
         
     $('#tt').html("<div id='message'></div>");
             $('#message').html(key + " : " + value);
    
    });

Comment: it print out "1220 : undefined"